# Moving a tab from one quicksight analysis to a different analyis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to copy a tab from one Quicksight analysis to a different analysis with the same dataset?

Answer (score 0):

No this has not been made available yet, the QuickSight team is working to launch a feature to export/import Analysis as code, which is yet to be launched.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33190375)